# Adaptive Payments application approval - average timescale?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, crowdsourcing, paypal-adaptive-payments

Does anyone have any idea of the average Adaptive Payments application approval time at the moment? It appears there may be a backlog as we've heard nothing from the moderators and it has been over 15 days (their usual timescale apparently). Our case is a crowdfunding website built on CodeIgniter with the Adaptive Payment gateway installed and ready to go live when we are given application approval. Our site has been active for 6months using other methods via PayPal, but it's time to move up a notch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the permissions your application is requesting; less restricted permissions usually goes through quicker.
Even so, check with PayPal Developer Technical Services at https://www.paypal.com/dts/ if you're looking for an update.

Comment: They are hugely vague with their replies unfortunately. I was hoping for some actual successful applicants to offer their final timescale. I don't think our application is out of the ordinary - oh well, watch this space. Already the sandbox transaction test on the site is working flawlessly, so I hope we're just on the brink of approval!